# Undefined variable in my Yii2 Model

Tags: variables, model, yii2, undefined

There is an error Undefined Variable when running my Model Class:

```
public $accountTypeFlag;

.......

public function getSecondType() {
      if (($this->$accountTypeFlag == 1)){
        return array (self::CURRENT_ASSETS=>'Current Assets',self::PROPERTY_AND_EQUIPMENT=>'Property and Equipment',self::OTHER_ASSETS=>'Other Assets');
        }
      if (($accountTypeFlag == 2)){
        return array (self::CURRENT_LIABILITIES=>'Current Liabilities');
        }
      if (($accountTypeFlag == 3)){
        return array (self::FUND_BALANCE=>'Fund Balance');
        }     
    }
```

Is there any way to read the accountTypeFlag inside the function?

Comment: `$this->accountTypeFlag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public $accountTypeFlag;

...

public function getSecondType() {
      if ($this->accountTypeFlag == 1) {
        ...
      } elseif ($this->accountTypeFlag == 2) {
        ...
      } elseif ($this->accountTypeFlag == 3) {
        ...
      }     
}
```